# How to for the XML using XDocument class from the below classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have two classes as

```
class WarningClass
{
        public string SqlEyeWarning { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
}

class RemarkClass
{
        public string SqlEyeRamark { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

They are populated as under

```
List<WarningClass> lstWarningClass = new List<WarningClass>();
lstWarningClass.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD001: Set QuotedIdentifier ON statement is missing" });
lstWarningClass.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "b.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD001: Set QuotedIdentifier ON statement is missing" });
lstWarningClass.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "c.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD009: Missing or order mismatch of Grant statement" });
lstWarningClass.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD009: Missing or order mismatch of Grant statement" });
lstWarningClass.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "d.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD004: Check for existence object then Drop statement before create statement" });



List<RemarkClass> lstRemarkClass = new List<RemarkClass>();
lstRemarkClass.Add(new RemarkClass { FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeRamark = "SD010: Set AnsiiNullsOn ON statement is missing" });
lstRemarkClass.Add(new RemarkClass { FileName = "b.sql", SqlEyeRamark = "SD002: Order mismatch or it should be ON." });
lstRemarkClass.Add(new RemarkClass { FileName = "c.sql", SqlEyeRamark = "SD002: Order mismatch or it should be ON." });
```

The desired output will be

```
<ScriptFileNames>
    <SqlEye>
        <SqlEyeWarnings Name="Set QuotedIdentifier ON statement is missing">
            <File Name="a.sql" />
            <File Name="b.sql" />
        </SqlEyeWarnings>
        <SqlEyeWarnings Name="SD009: Missing or order mismatch of Grant statement">
            <File Name="a.sql" />
            <File Name="c.sql" />
        </SqlEyeWarnings>
        <SqlEyeWarnings Name="SD004: Check for existence object then Drop statement before create statement">
            <File Name="d.sql" />           
        </SqlEyeWarnings>

        <SqlEyeRemarks Name="SD010: Set AnsiiNullsOn ON statement is missing">
            <File Name="a.sql" />           
        </SqlEyeRemarks>
        <SqlEyeRemarks Name="SD002: Order mismatch or it should be ON.">
            <File Name="b.sql" />   
            <File Name="c.sql" />
        </SqlEyeRemarks>
    </SqlEye>
</ScriptFileNames>
```

Comment: Are you sure that XML is correct? It looks very different from the XML in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938434/difficulty-in-reading-xml-values-using-xdocument

Comment: yes sir...i am sure about the xml

Comment: So why is it completely different between your two questions? And what have you tried so far to create the XML?

Comment: This I am trying.Actually the output the previous question has to be transformed into this xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("ScriptFileNames");
            xml.AppendChild(root);

            XmlElement comment = xml.CreateElement("SqlEye");
            root.AppendChild(comment);

            var WarningClassData = (from items in lstWarningClass
                                    select items).GroupBy(t => t.SqlEyeWarning).ToList();

            foreach (var data in WarningClassData)
            {
                XmlElement SqlEyeWarnings = xml.CreateElement("SqlEyeWarnings");
                SqlEyeWarnings.SetAttribute("Name", data.Key);
                comment.AppendChild(SqlEyeWarnings);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
                {
                    XmlElement File = xml.CreateElement("File");
                    File.SetAttribute("Name", data.ElementAt(i).FileName);
                    SqlEyeWarnings.AppendChild(File);
                }
            }

            var RemarkClassData = (from items in lstRemarkClass
                                   select items).GroupBy(t => t.SqlEyeRamark).ToList();

            foreach (var data in RemarkClassData)
            {
                XmlElement SqlEyeRemarks = xml.CreateElement("SqlEyeRemarks");
                SqlEyeRemarks.SetAttribute("Name", data.Key);
                comment.AppendChild(SqlEyeRemarks);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
                {
                    XmlElement File = xml.CreateElement("File");
                    File.SetAttribute("Name", data.ElementAt(i).FileName);
                    SqlEyeRemarks.AppendChild(File);
                }
            }

            xml.Save(@"F:\\test.xml")
```

Comment: how can we do the same using XDocument

Comment: this will also cater you you want it by Xdocument ???

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic data structure you could use:

```
class SqlEyeData
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<string> Filenames {get;set;}
}
```

This is the code you could use to populate these structures based on your previous code (tho' Bunny's Linq query with GroupBy is much more elegant):

```
var sqlEyeWarnings = new List<SqlEyeData>();
var uniqueWarningMessages = lstWarningClass.Select(warning => warning.SqlEyeWarning).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(msg => {
  sqlEyeWarnings.Add(new SqlEyeData()
  {
    Name = msg,
    Filenames = lstWarningClass.Where(warning => warning.SqlEyeWarning == msg).Select(warning => warning.FileName).ToList(),
  });
});
```

I've just done the WarningClass implementation, but the RemarkClass one is exactly the same with different property names. In fact, you could save yourself a whole lot of trouble by using a single class for WarningClass and RemarkClass as the only difference between them is the name of the string property.

Then you could do something like this to convert using XDocument:

```
public XElement GetSqlEyeDataElement(string elementName, SqlEyeData data)
{
    var returnValue = new XElement(elementName,
        new XAttribute("Name", data.Name)
    );
    data.Filenames.ForEach(filename =>
    {
        returnValue.Add(new XElement("File",
            new XAttribute("Name", filename)));
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```